# Como almacenar los indices que provienen de un formulario via $_POST

Tags: php, html

estoy haciendo un formulario que envía datos a un archivo php todo normal, el problema radica en que deseo recibir en ese archivo. Tanto los valores que provienen vía $_POST como los índices de estos valores.

si tengo el siguiente input:

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text">
```

y normalmente en el php recibiría:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

lo que quiero hacer es almacenar el nombre del índice y su valor en variables diferentes.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con los indices? No logro entender bien tu pregunta.

Comment: veras se supone que la variable $_POST es un array si no me equivoco, como todos los array poseen indices cuando escribes $_POST['indices'] lo que va dentro del corchete son los indices.

lo que quiero es poder almacenar esos incides en variables.

entendiendo que el indice de un array es diferente de el valor que contiene.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, ni se ve qué sentido tiene almacenar el nombre del índice (que en realidad sería la clave del array). Por ejemplo, tú puedes leer las claves/valores dentro del POST con algo como esto: `foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v){ echo "La clave es $k  y el valor es $v".PHP_EOL;}` en cada iteracción del bucle te imprimirá cada dato. Lo que me pregunto es la finalidad de querer almacenar las claves... Las mismas se suelen tirar desde el array de otros modos, por ejemplo, cuando se necesita una tabla cuyos encabezados sean las claves, pero almacenarlas, ¿qué sentido tendría?

Comment: porque deseo hacer un array con todo lo que pase via $_POST (claves/valores) para luego insertar en la base de datos usando las claves para comparar las claves contra los campos de una bd e insertarle esos valores.

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres hacer lo que ya tienes?  `$_POST`  es **precisamente un array**. Tú lo que tienes es recurrir a una técnica adecuada para leer los valores que hay dentro del POST. Por ejemplo,  si es para un `INSERT`, a través de funciones que ya existen en PHP puedes obtener las claves de `$_POST` para obtener las columnas y obtener los valores dentro de un bucle o con otra función, preparar una consulta y ejecutarla. Se trata de aplicar la estrategia adecuada con las funciones que ya existen para ello. Prueba esto por ejemplo: `print_r(array_keys($_POST[]));` y entenderás mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es lo que te comenta A. Cedano:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v){
    echo "La clave es $k y el valor es $v".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Ya que ***$_POST*** por si solo ya es una array, no tiene sentido volver a meter los valores en otro array.

Lo que alomejor tendría más sentido es que utilices el foreach para hacer un

`$k = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link , $v);`

lo que te da algo de seguridad si lo que quieres es insertarlo en una base de datos

De todas maneras la respuesta más lógica me parece la de **A. Cedano** ya que con su bucle puedes sacar los valores de las claves ( o índices como tú los llamas )

Answer (score -1):

```
$array=$_POST;
while ($elemento = current($array)) {
    if($elemento=="username")
    {
      $username=$elemento;
    }   

    next($array);
}
```

Comment: Hola, tu publicación es considerada como de baja calidad, agrega una descripción de como tu código soluciona el problema del autor. Para mas información revisa [answer]